# Expressing the concept of "spreading oneself shallowly" in English

Tags: phrase-requests

The words in bold in the quote below are meant to express something that I don't know how to put in English. The main idea is that someone is spending too much energy in many different areas thinking that he is going to achieve some considerable progress in all of them while in fact he is only going to enjoy a small amount of success (if any) in all those areas due to the enormous scale of area.

> Jack: So what project did you choose for this semester?
>
> Linda: The children illiteracy in in-land towns in Uganda, The
>   correlation between humans' eating habits and their behavioral
>   patterns, The possibility of practical application of the Poincaré
>   conjecture solution in the nearest future, The affect of globing
>   warming on blue whales migratory patterns...
>
> Jack: Wow! Isn't it too many? Why not focus on only one project and
>   research it thoroughly instead? I suggest that you should not
>   **shallowly spread yourself on so many** projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of an idiom that exactly expresses your meaning.  We can suggest to Linda that she should not *spread herself so thinly*, but that suggests the risk of failure, rather than insufficient progress.

If Linda lives her life this way, she might become a *jack of all trades, but master of none*.  I.e. she has acquired many "shallow skills" through her diverse experiences, but no deep ones.

Answer (score 12):

The colloquial form is *you should not spread yourself so thinly*.

Comment: *thinly*? Or *thin*? (*thinly* would modify _spread_, *thin* would modify _yourself_)

Comment: If I spread butter on bread I modify the verb with 'thinly', not the noun with 'thin'. That's the analogy.

Comment: The Carpenter said nothing but
 "The butter's spread too thick!" [The Walrus and the Carpenter](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html)

Comment: @sq33G: Yes, in such contexts 'spread' can be seen as a copulative verb having the adjective phrase as its complement. However, in the OP's example 'thin' risks being read as a non-standard adverb. That's fine if that is the intention, but in most contexts it probably won't be.

Comment: checked this on [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spread+yourself+too+thin%2Cspread+yourself+too+thinly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Both forms seem to be in use, though there's a reason why "thin" sounds more right to my mind's ear. And when limited to American English, "thinly" disappears altogether.

Comment: Perhaps another transatlantic difference then.

Comment: @Barrie - Thank you for your answer. The only reason why I didn't choose it as the best answer is because this form doesn't reflect Linda's presumptuousness - a self-ambitious self-confidence. I admit that my example didn't clearly showed that negative side of Linda. I am sorry for that.